# Node application uploading gltf files to s3 bucket but all files become 0kb (or corrupted)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, backend

I was using my node app to upload .glb files to my s3 bucket , it does upload but the files are 0kb and can't be used. here is the code

I have tried changing the file type to even trying a new bucket , no avail.

With my old code , when the upload button was pressed , two files appeared on the bucket .... one with the correct name (ie abc.glb) and one with the data but the name undefined

--

```
const uploadFile = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const file = req.file;
    const userId = req.body.userId;
    const fileName = req.body.fileName;

    
    const uploadResult = await s3Client.send(
      new PutObjectCommand({
        Bucket: 'mybucket',
        Key: `${fileName}.glb`,
        Body: file.buffer,
        ContentType: 'model/gltf-binary',
        ACL: 'public-read',
      })
    );

    console.log('Successfully uploaded object:', uploadResult);

    // Construct the file URL based on the unique file name
    const fileUrl = `https://bucket-url/${req.body.fileName}.glb`;

    console.log('File URL:', fileUrl);

    const qrCode = await qrcode.toDataURL(fileUrl);

    console.log('QR Code:', qrCode);

    const product = new GLTFFile({
      fileName,
      fileUrl,
      fileType: file.mimetype,
      qrCode,
      user: userId,
      status: 'uploading',
    });

    console.log('Product:', product);

    await product.save();

    
    req.file.stream.end();

    res.json(product);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error uploading file' });
  }
};
```

Tried changing lot of stuff , nothing helped